# Cake Bake generated code (scaffolding) resulting in syntax error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bake

Cake Bake generated the following code snipped:

```
public function index()
{
$this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Users']
    ];

    $shops = $this->paginate($this->Shops);

    $this->set(compact('shops'));
}
```

The result is the error message: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

When I change the code to this it works:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Users']
    ];

    // $shops = $this->paginate($this->Shops);
    $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
    $shops = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->Shops->find());

    $this->set(compact('shops'));
}
```

I find this strange in particular because the first code version is generated by cake bake and supposed to work straight away, isnt it?

Comment: There's no such syntax error in that code snippet, so the problem is somewhere else. Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the complete error**, that is, including **the full stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion) - thanks!

Comment: You are right the problem must have been caused by me. What I did to solve was to regenerate the code by baking again and then it worked. I will post whole error report next time. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: What am i supposed to do now to adhere to stack policy? Delete the question?